# Angular15 and msal-angularv3: How to solve Error: Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled

Tags: angular, authentication, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

## Details and Problem

Hey all,
My angular application is currently running **version15 **and I've integrated the `msal-angular` and `msal-browser` module.

My application is using the

```
login.popup Interaction.Type.
```

I've had the **common issue** with msal-angular **version2** of not resolving popups when using the **edge browser**:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5091

I've thought about updating to a **newer** msal-angular version.

## What I've tried

So I've **updated** to:

```
"@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.4",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.1.0",
```

After running my application in **edge** I got following error:

```
ERROR BrowserAuthError: uninitialized_public_client_application: 
You must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API. 
For more visit: aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors
```

I'm following this official tutorial: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/v2-migration.md

The main thing I updated wasin my
app.module.ts

```
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'clientID',
    authority:
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant',
    redirectUri: location.origin,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
    clientCapabilities: ['CP1'],
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
await msalInstance.initialize();
```

When addind this: `await msalInstance.initialize();`

I cannot start the app and it shows this error:
`Error: Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled`

I've no clue what to do and would really appreciate any help.

full app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';

import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {
  MsalBroadcastService,
  MsalGuard,
  MsalInterceptor,
  MsalModule,
  MsalRedirectComponent,
  MsalService,
} from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { CustomerService } from './_services/customer.service';
import { VMService } from './_services/vm.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//import { WelcomeComponent } from './components/archived/welcome/welcome.component';
import { CustomerDetailComponent } from './components/customer/customer-detail/customer-detail.component';
import { CustomerQueryComponent } from './components/customer/customer-query/customer-query.component';
import { CustomerComponent } from './components/customer/customer/customer.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { VMListComponent } from './components/vmList/vmList.component';

import {
  BrowserCacheLocation,
  InteractionType,
  PublicClientApplication,
} from '@azure/msal-browser';

import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';
import { AlertService } from './_services/alert.service';
import { AlertComponent } from './components/helper/alert/alert.component';
import { LoadingSpinnerComponent } from './components/helper/loading-spinner/loading-spinner.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { RemoteProtocolModalComponent } from './components/remote-protocol-modal/remote-protocol-modal.component';
import { UnauthorizedComponent } from './components/unauthorized/unauthorized.component';
import { protectedResources } from './constants/auth.config';

/*const isIE =
  window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 ||
  window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;
*/

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'clientID',
    authority:
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant',
    redirectUri: location.origin,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
    clientCapabilities: ['CP1'],
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
await msalInstance.initialize();

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomerComponent,
    CustomerDetailComponent,
    CustomerQueryComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    VMListComponent,
    //WelcomeComponent,
    RemoteProtocolModalComponent,
    LoadingSpinnerComponent,
    AlertComponent,
    UnauthorizedComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot(
      msalInstance,
      {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Popup, // MSAL Guard Configuration
        authRequest: {
          scopes: [protectedResources.vmWebhookAPI.scope],
        },
      },
      {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Popup, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
        protectedResourceMap: new Map([
          [
            protectedResources.vmWebhookAPI.endpoints.Customers,
            [protectedResources.vmWebhookAPI.scope],
          ],
          [
            protectedResources.vmWebhookAPI.endpoints.CustomerSetting,
            [protectedResources.vmWebhookAPI.scope],
          ],
          [
            protectedResources.vmWebhookAPI.endpoints.AzureRest,
            [protectedResources.vmWebhookAPI.scope],
          ],
        ]),
      }
    ),
  ],
  providers: [
    AlertService,
    VMService,
    CustomerService,
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

full angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "vm-hub-ui": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/vm-hub-ui",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-bs5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-fixedheader-bs5/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap5.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-bs5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-fixedheader-bs5/js/fixedHeader.bootstrap5.min.js",
              "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5  mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "options": {
            "port": 44307
          },
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "vm-hub-ui:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "vm-hub-ui:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "vm-hub-ui:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  }
}
```

Full package.json

```
{
  "name": "vm-hub-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "compodoc": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json -w -s"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.4",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@types/datatables.net-fixedcolumns": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "angular-datatables": "^15.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
    "datatables": "^1.10.18",
    "datatables.net": "^1.13.2",
    "datatables.net-bs5": "^1.13.2",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^2.3.4",
    "datatables.net-buttons-bs5": "^2.3.4",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^2.3.4",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.13.2",
    "datatables.net-fixedcolumns": "^4.2.1",
    "datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs5": "^4.2.1",
    "datatables.net-fixedheader": "^3.3.1",
    "datatables.net-fixedheader-bs5": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.48.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.48.2",
    "eslint": "^8.33.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```